# Need to Create a stored procedure to update table

Tags: postgresql

I am looking to update a Table B from Table A (Master Table) when ever a new record is published.
the table data is same and just a dump to table B to maintain more data volume.

I am looking to write a stored proc for this and below is what i have, but it throws an error at the begin statement

ID column is the unique identifier here. and DB is PostgreSQL

```
create or replace procedure proc 1 ()
as
begin
      INSERT into table B (Col1, Col2, Col3, etc)
             select (Col1, Col2, Col3, etc) from table A
             where not exists (
             select (Col1, Col2, Col3, etc)
             from    table B     
             where table A.id = TableB.id  
end
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: " just a dump to table B to maintain more data volume." ?   While I'm sure people could help you with what you asked, it seems very unusual.  I doubt if you actually need this.   PLease see : https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: We need to maintain 2 years of data in Table B and 1 year in Table A.... Thats the req... so we need to dump to other table and Archive.... Appreciate your sarcasm though

Comment: I wasn't using any sarcasm.  You truly have the X/Y problem. To achieve your goals, refer to this: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-partitioning.html